Equality of an integral of a measurable function
I have a question about an exercise in a book about measure theory/integration. In the first part I have to show that:
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu = \sup\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \inf\{f(x):x∈ A_k\}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\dots,A_n∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right\}.
$$
where $f:X\to[0,\infty]$ is a non-negative measurable function (the definition of left hand-side is the standard definition of integrals of non-negative measurable functions). I think I have found a solution and proved this. The second part of the exercise askes if the equality above still holds if we use countable partitions instead of (only) finite partitions. I would say that this statement is still true because you can "approximate" every countable partition with a sequence of finite partitions and in this case the supremum is not affected. I am not absolutely sure if I am correct. Has someone an idea? Thank you for your help!

What is $\mathfrak{A}$?

The set $\mathfrak{A}$ consists of all the measurable sets of the measure space $(X,\mathfrak{A}, \mu)$.

If you've shown the first part, then you've probably bounded $\sum_{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k)\le \int_X f,d\mu$. What part of your proof do you think doesn't transfer to the infinite case?

Yes this is true, the function you gave on left hand-side (I call it $g$) is a non-negative simple function $0≤g≤f$ so your given inequality follows. Maybe the problem that could arise is (when $n\to∞$) that $∫_X g,d\mu$ would become infinity where $∫_X f,d\mu$ is finite. But I don't know if this could happen...

Note that $\mu(A_k) = \int {A_k} d\mu$. Use that together with linearity and monotocity, and you can show the bound $\sum{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k)\le \int_X f,d\mu$. Then for the infinite case you can show the more general result $\int_{\Omega}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_nd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\Omega} f_nd\mu$ for non-negative measurable functions $f_n$ using monotone convergence.

Thank you! So that means that the given equality is also true with infinite partitions, am I correct?

@Sudix  Do you mean I should show
$$
\int_X \sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\cdot \chi_{A_k},d\mu
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_X\inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\cdot \chi_{A_k},d\mu
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\cdot \mu(A_k),d\mu
\leq \int_X f,d\mu
$$
for the infinite case?

Let $(X,\mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space.Let $f_n:X\toℝ_{\ge 0}$ for all $n\inℕ$ be a non-negative measurable function. Then we have:
$$
\int_{X}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_nd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{X} f_nd\mu
$$
I'll leave the proof of above to you.
Using this, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf\{f(x):x∈ A_k\}\mu(A_k)
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf\{f(x):x∈ A_k\}\int_{X} _{A_k} d\mu
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{X} \inf\{f(x):x∈ A_k\} _{A_k} d\mu
\\&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{X} f\cdot _{A_k} d\mu
\\&=\int_{X} \sum_{k=1}^\infty f\cdot _{A_k} d\mu
\\&= \int_X f\,d\mu
\end{align}$$

Thank you! I asked myself if it wouldn't be sufficient only to use limit rules: If you set $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$ then $(s_n)n$ would be an increasing sequence bounded by $\int_X f,d\mu$ as in your comment above, hence it is convergent. Now the limit-rule $a_n\leq b_n \implies \lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$ for convergent sequences would imply $$\lim s_n = \sum{k=1}^\infty\inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)\leq \int_x f,d\mu.$$ Shouldn't this also work?
Then to finish the whole argument it remains to prove that $\int_X f,d\mu \leq \lim s_n$, am I right?

@RobRTex You can make this argument work, but there's quite a bit missing at this point. The first is to note that you need to show that the infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$ can actually be obtained as a limit of a $(s_n){n\in ℕ}$. This is not trivial since the $A_k$ need to be disjoint, so how does the sequence $((A_k^{(n)}){k\in[n]})_{n\inℕ}$ look that this works? (A standard argument does the trick here)

@RobRTex Once this is done you have shown that any sum $S:= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$ can be obtained as a limit of sequences of series. But what we actually need to show is that the supremum of any sequences of series of the form $S$ can be obtained. The bound you've given shows this, but one should be aware that this might not be trivial, so it's worth mentioning in the proof.

Thank you very much for your great help! I think I don't see the point...if I have an infinite partition $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ then $\lim s_n = \lim \sum_{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$ is the definition of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$ - so it must be a obtained as a limit of the $(s_n)_n$. Isn't that true? So I don't see why I have to construct another sequence of $A_k$'s...

@RobRTex Let the infinite partition be given by $(A_n){n\inℕ}$. Then $(A_1,...,A_n)$ needn't be a partition.  So while we indeed have that $\lim s_n := \lim \sum{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x\in A_k}\mu(A_k)$, we may have $s_n\notin \left{\sum_{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\dots,A_n∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right}$!

Oh yes, of course! Thank you! To finish all up we finally get:
$$
\int_X f,d\mu = \sup\left{\sum_{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\dots,A_n∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right} \leq  \sup\left{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\ldots ∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right} \leq \int_X f,d\mu.
$$
The first inequality since every finite partion is a special infinite partion using the empty set and the general rule $A\subset B\implies \sup A\leq\sup B$. So finally we got it?

I thought about your "standard trick" above...Maybe I can approximate the partion $A_1,\dots$ with the sequence of finite partions $(A_1,X\setminus A_1), (A_1,A_2, X\setminus (A_1\cup A_2))$, so in general $(A_1,\dots,A_n, X\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$.

@RobRTex Yes, that's exactly the argument I had in mind! Your method with the empty set has its merits as well, and we have now arguments to put together the same proof in multiple ways. E.g. the whole argumentation in the comments together is one proof. Or we can shorten it, using only your comment which I upvoted together with the main answer. Alternatively, we can use your comment which I upvoted together with the standard trick, since both together show that

$$\left{\sum_{k=1}^n \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\dots,A_n∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right} =  \left{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \inf{f(x):x∈ A_k}\mu(A_k):n∈\mathbb{N}, A_1,\ldots ∈\mathfrak{A} \text{ disjoint}, X = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right}$$

Perfect! Thank you very much for your help and sharing your ideas!
